# Acumatica 6.0 WSE returning data in gzip encoding

Tags: gzip, acumatica

The Web Service Endpoint functionality has changed for 6.0 and now the responses to requests are GZIP encoded.  Is there a way to disable this when sending in the WSE requests?

We have a C++ DLL that has been working with Acumatica 5.3 without issue but as soon as we upgraded one of our test systems to 6.0 we can no longer process responses.  Longer term we will address this by adding GZIP support to our code, however in the short-term we need to be able to support 6.0 without having to do significant changes to our code.

For example in the 5.3 version we sent the following request

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns="acumatica.com/entity/5.30.001.004/OzLINK_WSE/… xsi:type="StockItem">
<InventoryID xsi:type="StringSearch">
<Value>5001</Value>
<Condition>Equal<‌​/Condition>
</Invento‌​ryID>
</entity>
</Get>‌​
</soap:Body>
</soap:E‌​nvelope>
```

and this correctly returned the data for Stock Item 5001. NOTE: ALL THE XMLNS elements are in the Envelope tag.

However in 6.0 that same request fails with a large error message and we found that we had to change the request to move the XMLNS elements

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Get xmlns="acumatica.com/entity/5.30.001.004/OzLINK_WSE/… xsi:type="StockItem"><ReturnBehavior>All</ReturnBehavior>
<In‌​ventoryID xsi:type="StringSearch">
<Value>5001</Value>
<Condition>Equal<‌​/Condition
></Invento‌​ryID>
</entity>
</Get>‌​</soap:Body></soap:E‌​nvelope>
```

We have also noticed that the structure of the XML returned by 6.0 is slightly different, we now have a p4 namespace that wasn't there before, this is causing some issues with our parsing logic which we are addressing at present.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: At some point we managed to implement our API in such a way that built-in IIS compression kicks in, but what bothers us is that compression should be adaptive, i.e., it should not enable unless client sends appropriate `Accept` header. Can you verify this behavior with Fiddler or other HTTP sniffer? Thanks.

Comment: Gabriel, after further research that wasn't actually the issue, you are correct the GZIP is only returned if we send correct Accept header.  The issue is actually a little more serious for us but that may be because we didn't fully implement the originally C++ code correctly.

Comment: For example in the 5.3 version we sent the following request '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/entity/5.30.001.004/OzLINK_WSE/"><soap:Body><Get><entity xsi:type="StockItem"><InventoryID xsi:type="StringSearch"><Value>5001</Value><Condition>Equal</Condition></InventoryID></entity></Get></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>' and this correctly returned the data for Stock Item 5001.  NOTE: ALL THE XMLNS elements are in the Envelope tag.

Comment: However in 6.0 that same request fails with a large error message and we found that we had to change the request to move the XMLNS elements '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Get xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/entity/5.30.001.004/OzLINK_WSE/"><entity xsi:type="StockItem"><ReturnBehavior>All</ReturnBehavior><InventoryID xsi:type="StringSearch"><Value>5001</Value><Condition>Equal</Condition></InventoryID></entity></Get></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'

Comment: We have also noticed that the structure of the XML returned by 6.0 is slightly different, we now have a p4 namespace that wasn't there before, this is causing some issues with our parsing logic which we are addressing at present.

Comment: Are you handcrafting the XML and envelope or using a standard library? You might be interested in knowing that we support REST+JSON with 6.0 which could reduce your headaches if you're manually crafting queries to the endpoints

Comment: Chris, can you edit your question so that it shows your current problem with xml messages?